# cd - が使えなくなりました。直前のディレクトリに戻るにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

Tags: command-line, zsh

ディレクトリの移動を何度か繰り返したあとに、
`cd -`
を実行しますが、いろいろと設定をいじっているうちに使用できなくなりました。

`-: no such file or directory`
とでるので、直前にいたディレクトリがキャッシュされていないのかと思うのですが、解決策がわかりません。

直前にいたディレクトリにもどるにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

Comment: [ここは](https://qiita.com/sasaplus1/items/16991eeb0247b905b06d)参考になりますか

Comment: which cd を実行するとなんて出ますか?

Comment: `which cd` を行うとこうでました。

Comment: ```cd: aliased to __enhancd::cd```

Answer (score 0):

以前は `setopt autopushd` が設定されていたのではないでしょうか。

`~/.zshrc` などに `setopt autopushd` を追加してから zsh を起動してみてください。

Comment: `setopt aut_pushd` が記述してありました。`setopt sutopushd` に変更してみましたがだめでした。。。